# Is it possible to use a user display form in a page?

Tags: 8, forms, users

I've seen that it's possible to create different user display form here :

/admin/config/people/accounts/form-display/my_infos_form

How can I call it in a particular page for instance : /my/infos ?

As we have a lot of fields, we would like to separate the user edit page into multiple form page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike view modes there is no UI in core to apply different form modes other than the user register form. You can try one of these modules:

https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_control

https://www.drupal.org/project/form_mode_manager